# Flatpickr rangePlugin issue

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr last distribution + rangePlugin.
As of right now I use the "setDate" function on the flatpickr instance to set the first date but if I just put both dates in there it only shows up in the first input like so:

[image]

```
instance.setDate([
            new Date().setHours(22),
            new Date().setHours(24)
          ])
```

Anyone have a clue to fix it ?